# Racket: Product of even number

Tags: racket

I am trying to produce the product of the even numbers in a given list. 
I am trying to replicate the following example:

Example: 
(product-even-numbers '(2 1 6 3 5))
==>   12

This is my version of the definition for product-even-numbers:

```
(define (product-even-numbers lst)
  (define/match (recurse lst accumulator)
    ;; A _ pattern matches any syntax object
    [(_ _) (* car (recurse cdr))])
  (recurse lst 1))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
(product-even-numbers '(2 1 6 3 5))
. . recurse: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: 2
  given: 1
  arguments...:
```

I understand that i am missing the second argument, but I do not know what the second argument is supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using pattern matching? this would be easier to understand without it, and first of all you need to get the recursion and the logic right:

```scm
(define (product-even-numbers lst)
  (define (recurse lst acc)
    (cond ((null? lst) acc)
          ((even? (car lst)) (recurse (cdr lst) (* (car lst) acc)))
          (else (recurse (cdr lst) acc))))
  (recurse lst 1))
```

In this case, it's clear that the second argument is the accumulated product we have so far. And we need to consider three cases: empty list, even element, odd element. For example:

```scm
(product-even-numbers '(2 1 6 3 5))
=> 12
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. I thought pattern matching for even would have done the trick, but this solution clearly shows that it would not have worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (product-even-numbers lst)
  (local [(define tmp (foldr * 1 (filter even? lst)))]
    (if (= 1 tmp) 'nothing tmp)))
```

If output 1 means no any even number.

```
(define (product-even-numbers2 lst)
  (foldr * 1 (filter even? lst))) ; or use (apply * (filter even? lst))
```